# Switching from Qt 5.7 to Qt 5.8 - "the proxy type is invalid for this operation"

Tags: c++, qt, proxy, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I'm trying to re-compile a networking application that worked fine with Qt 5.7 using Qt 5.8. However, using Qt 5.8, the server fails to `listen()`:

```
int myPort = 52000; //some accessible port
QTcpServer* server = new QTcpServer();
if(!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, myPort))
{
    qDebug() << server.errorString();
}
```

and the returned error is:

> The proxy type is invalid for this operation

I do run the application on a corporate network that is protected by a proxy, however in previous versions of Qt have never had to do any type of setup to account for that. I've never seen the `listen()` command fail before.

Any ideas what changed in Qt 5.8 or how to account for this?

*EDIT:*

while the overall network is proxied, no proxy is required to communicate on the local domain, and the `NO_PROXY` environment variable is set to avoid proxying of local connections.

Comment: `QNetworkProxyFactory::usesSystemConfiguration` returns anything fancy?

Comment: You can see api changes here http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html but I don't see anything that should cause that!

Comment: There seems to be at least 2 changes in Qt default configuration related to proxies: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/dist/changes-5.8.0

Comment: @peppe it returns `true` by default, which seems strange. If I set `QNetworkProxyFactory::useSystemConfiguration(false);`, my application works again. This smells like a bug to me, especially since I have the `NO_PROXY` variable set for my local network. Maybe because I don't use fully qualified domain names for the hostnames? But I shouldn't have to...

Comment: @alexisdm "Proxies from system settings will now be used by default." seems like the culprit. Gotta love breaking changes buried deeply in the release notes. It should have been put on [new features page](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qt 5.8, system proxy settings are used by default, but don't seem to respect the `NO_PROXY` settings.

Setting `QNetworkProxyFactory::useSystemConfiguration(false);` prior to creating the `QTcpServer` instance fixed the error (essentially by reverting the the Qt 5.7 default).

Answer (score 1):

In older Qt versions (5.4.3 for example) where `QNetworkProxyFactory::useSystemConfiguration(false);` isn't available the following sequence can be used:

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
proxy.setType(QNetworkProxy::HttpProxy);
proxy.setHostName("proxy.example.com");
proxy.setPort(1080);
proxy.setUser("username");
proxy.setPassword("password");
QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

Or just:

```
QNetworkProxy proxy;
QNetworkProxy::setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

This worked for me, posting here for records purposes.