# Pyqt5 the proxy type is invalid for this operation

Tags: python, pyqt5

I use [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65491018/pyqt5-destroyed-while-thread-is-still-running) code before, and it works for me.
But now, something change, and i have that error:

```
the proxy type is invalid for this operation
```

I figured out it still work if proxy settings is off, but what i should to do to solve this problem with proxy?

Thats an example of code what i use:

```
from functools import cached_property
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtNetwork


class Client(QtCore.QObject):
    messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.socket.stateChanged.connect(self.handle_state_changed)
        self.socket.errorOccurred.connect(self.handle_error_occurred)
        self.socket.readyRead.connect(self.handle_ready_read)

    @cached_property
    def socket(self):
        return QtNetwork.QTcpSocket()

    def try_connect(self):
        self.socket.connectToHost("127.0.0.1", 5555)

    def handle_state_changed(self, state):
        print(f"state: {state}")
        if state == QtNetwork.QAbstractSocket.UnconnectedState:
            print("disconnected")
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.try_connect)
        elif state == QtNetwork.QAbstractSocket.ConnectedState:
            print("connected")

    def handle_error_occurred(self, error):
        print(f"error code {error}, message: {self.socket.errorString()}")

    def handle_ready_read(self):
        codec = QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8")
        message = codec.toUnicode(self.socket.readAll())
        self.messageChanged.emit(message)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.client.messageChanged.connect(self.handle_message_changed)
        self.client.try_connect()

    @cached_property
    def client(self):
        return Client()

    def handle_message_changed(self, message):
        print(f"client message: {message}")


def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also i saw that [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42121008/switching-from-qt-5-7-to-qt-5-8-the-proxy-type-is-invalid-for-this-operation), but i didnt get how can i use that in my code.

Comment: Are you asking how to make it work bypassing the existing proxy? It seems that the linked solution is what you should do, what's not clear about that?

Comment: @musicamante yeah, idk how can i make it work with existing proxy. I can't turn off proxy settings on my windows.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I should to set a "NoProxy" type, before connection. Like in [that](https://forum.qt.io/topic/76119/socket-connecttohost-doesn-t-work-in-qt-5-8) topic.

my example:

```
class Client(QtCore.QObject):
messageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.proxy = QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy(QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy.NoProxy)
    self.socket.stateChanged.connect(self.handle_state_changed)
    self.socket.errorOccurred.connect(self.handle_error_occurred)
    self.socket.readyRead.connect(self.handle_ready_read)

@cached_property
def socket(self):
    return QtNetwork.QTcpSocket()

def try_connect(self):
    self.socket.setProxy(self.proxy)
    self.socket.connectToHost("ADDRESS", PORT)
```

That worked for me.